# get unique device information from browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, user-agent

in the time of user security, is there any way to find out from which device (computer name or any unique info), the user accesses a server? And also a way that is not changing in future!

I am using a combination of Angular or javascript and ASP.Net.
The problem is that my customers make pay transactions from different dwvices and I would like, also for the customers, to log where a payment transaction was done (not which user).

Comment: What you're looking for is the `User-Agent` header which will contain some information on the device the client is using.

Comment: Yes, but these information are not secure to be received right, and it is not save that the browsers (chrome firefox aso.) will always support these